# Meaning of trademark "unrevivable"

Tags: trademark

I am trying to get the meaning of a Trademark statement. 
A filing is: continued use not filed within grace period, unrevivable.

Answer (score 2):

A registered trademark is only valid for a set period of time.

The trademark registration will become invalid if the owner does not renew it within a deadline set by the law.

- "Continued use not filed within grace period" means that the trademark registration you are looking at was not renewed in time. It has thus run out and is no longer valid.
- "Unrevivable" means that this particular trademark registration cannot become active again.

Note that the duration of a trademark registration and the deadlines depend on your jurisdiction.

Comment: To be clear, it doesn't mean that this trademark can't be registered ever again, but that you'd have to start from scratch, not simply renew/revive the previous one. Also, its not a set period of time, and its not really a renewal, its just a statement of continued use. This answer is basically correct though